# Deserialize JSON using restsharp

Tags: c#, json, deserialization, restsharp

I am trying to deserialize data from Harvest but its failing (no error): https://github.com/harvesthq/api#api-json

The data returned looks like this:

**Updated**
(see at the bottom for complete JSON response)

The output when i run the code below is a list with x posts where each post contains an id = 0

Is there a setting or something that i have missed to make it ignore/parse the surrounding []?

```
[DeserializeAs(Name = "project")]
public class Project
{
    public int id { get; set; }

    //public string name { get; set; }

    //[DeserializeAs(Name = "created-at")]
    //public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }           
}

// The following is the methods to request for testing

public List<Project> GetProjects()
{
    var request = new RestRequest("projects", Method.GET);
    request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
    return Execute<List<Project>>(request);
}

private T Execute<T>(RestRequest request) where T : new()
{
    var client = new RestClient();            
    client.BaseUrl = BaseUrl;
    client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator(_username, _password);
    var response = client.Execute<T>(request);

    if (response.ErrorException != null)
    {
        const string message = "Error retrieving response.  Check inner details for more info.";
        var exception = new ApplicationException(message, response.ErrorException);
        throw exception;
    }
    return response.Data;
}
```

Data returned from Harvest:

```
[
  {
    "project": {
      "id": 123456,
      "client_id": 219854,
      "name": "Test proj 1",
      "code": "",
      "active": false,
      "billable": true,
      "bill_by": "Tasks",
      "cost_budget": null,
      "cost_budget_include_expenses": false,
      "hourly_rate": null,
      "budget": 8,
      "budget_by": "project",
      "notify_when_over_budget": false,
      "over_budget_notification_percentage": 80,
      "over_budget_notified_at": null,
      "show_budget_to_all": false,
      "created_at": "2014-04-03T09:49:00Z",
      "updated_at": "2014-07-02T11:45:07Z",
      "estimate": 8,
      "estimate_by": "project",
      "hint_earliest_record_at": "2014-04-03",
      "hint_latest_record_at": "2014-04-03",
      "notes": ""
    }
  },
  {
    "project": {
      "id": 234567,
      "client_id": 686547,
      "name": "Test porj 2",
      "code": "",
      "active": true,
      "billable": true,
      "bill_by": "Tasks",
      "cost_budget": null,
      "cost_budget_include_expenses": false,
      "hourly_rate": null,
      "budget": 8,
      "budget_by": "project",
      "notify_when_over_budget": false,
      "over_budget_notification_percentage": 80,
      "over_budget_notified_at": null,
      "show_budget_to_all": false,
      "created_at": "2014-04-03T09:48:28Z",
      "updated_at": "2014-04-15T20:47:29Z",
      "estimate": 8,
      "estimate_by": "project",
      "hint_earliest_record_at": "2014-04-03",
      "hint_latest_record_at": "2014-04-03",
      "notes": ""
    }
  },
  {
    "project": {
      "id": 345678,
      "client_id": 987456,
      "name": "Test proj 3",
      "code": "",
      "active": false,
      "billable": true,
      "bill_by": "Project",
      "cost_budget": null,
      "cost_budget_include_expenses": false,
      "hourly_rate": null,
      "budget": 8,
      "budget_by": "project",
      "notify_when_over_budget": false,
      "over_budget_notification_percentage": 80,
      "over_budget_notified_at": null,
      "show_budget_to_all": false,
      "created_at": "2013-04-26T13:21:35Z",
      "updated_at": "2014-03-30T18:05:24Z",
      "estimate": 8,
      "estimate_by": "project",
      "hint_earliest_record_at": "2013-04-26",
      "hint_latest_record_at": "2013-12-04",
      "notes": "Scriblings from meeting ..."
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: same question and answers here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8637288/loading-a-json-file-containing-json-within-brackets

the short of it is, when there's brackets, it's supposed to be containing an array.   Are you getting back multiple JSON objects in the brackets, or is it only one?    If it's an array of objects, you have to parse it accordingly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're misinterpreting the JSON response.

```
[
  {
    "project": {
      "id": 123456
    }
  },
  {
    "project": {
      "id": 234567
    }
  }
]
```

That's an array with objects that contain a `Project`. I'm not familiar with RestSharp, but something like this should do:

```
public class SomeType
{
    public Project project { get; set; }
}
```

```
return Execute<List<SomeType>>(request);
```

You might want to get in touch with the project maintainers though, according to [the documentation](https://github.com/harvesthq/api/blob/master/Sections/Projects.md#show-all-projects) `/projects` should return an array of projects.

Answer (score 4):

As Stijn mentioned your service is returning an array of a container object with a property of the type project.

I took the liberty to recreate your code sample with the fix suggested by Stijn see it below.

```
using RestSharp;
using RestSharp.Deserializers;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program p = new Program();

            var project = p.GetProjects();
        }

        public class ProjectResult 
        {
            public Project project { get; set; }
        }

        public class Project
        {
            public int id { get; set; }
        }

        public List<ProjectResult> GetProjects()
        {
            var request = new RestRequest("projects", Method.GET);
            request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
            return Execute<List<ProjectResult>>(request);
        }

        private T Execute<T>(RestRequest request) where T : new()
        {
            var client = new RestClient();
            client.BaseUrl = "http://127.0.0.1:1337/";
            //client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator(_username, _password);
            var response = client.Execute<T>(request);

            if (response.ErrorException != null)
            {
                const string message = "Error retrieving response.  Check inner details for more info.";
                var exception = new ApplicationException(message, response.ErrorException);
                throw exception;
            }
            return response.Data;
        }
    }
}
```